# Python string plus extra data, mutability

Tags: python, string

I'm looking for a Python class that behaves exactly like `str` execpt that

- it should be mutable, i.e., its content modifyable in-place, and
- it should carry some extra data.

This

```py
class MyString(str):
    def __init__(self, string):
        super().__init__()
        self._foo = "more data"


a = MyString("123")

print(a)
print(isinstance(a, str))
```

```
123
True
more data
```

works for the extra-data part, but I'm not sure if I can modify `"123"`.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual string data itself *cannot* be mutable with a subclass of `str`; `str` data is immutable.

If you need something that behaves in a string-like manner and you can mutate, you might build on top of [`collections.UserString`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserString), but even there you'd need to override additional methods to make it mutable, replacing the `data` member with a new `str` when you mutate it.

If you can live with raw binary data, not text data, subclassing `bytearray` might get you what you want, since `bytearray` is a mutable type. You could even override `__str__` so it automatically decodes (based on a common default encoding, or one provided to the initializer) when stringified.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want:

```
class MyString(str):
    def __init__(self, string):
        super().__init__()
        self.string = string
        self._foo = "more data"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.string

    def modify(self, new_string):
        self.string = new_string


a = MyString("123")

print(a)
print(isinstance(a, str))
print(a._foo)

a.modify("456")

print(a)
print(isinstance(a, str))
print(a._foo)
```

Output:

```
123
True
more data
456
True
more data
```

Comment: There is little reason to subclass `str` here (aside from claiming to be a subclass). You're not using the actual `str` data storage consistently (when `__str__` is involved you use the `.string` attribute, when it's not, you only see whatever was passed when *originally* constructed, ignoring all mutations via `modify` or direct manipulation of `.string`). Using `+=` on it will produce a plain `str` w/o mutating in-place, echoing interactively uses the original value, etc. End result is neither fully mutable nor fully immutable, and the mixture is going to confuse consumers of the class.

Comment: To make it behave as fully mutable type, you'd need to override basically every operator/method `str` provides, and effectively ignore the data it *thinks* it holds in favor of your custom attribute (at which point you've derived essentially zero benefit from being a `str` subclass). And even then, certain C-level APIs (used implicitly for certain Python level operations) might incorrectly use the underlying `str` data storage, not what you've overridden it with, and you're still betwixt and between, worse off than if you'd implemented the class from scratch.